# How to choose a unique ip on days(1 unique ip in every day)?

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli

**Structure table:**

```
date  (datetime)
ip    (varchat,50)
```

**I have query:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table GROUP BY ip Order by date Desc
```

Tell me please how to choose a unique ip on days(1 unique ip in every day)?

[image: data]

**me need get next result:**

```
2013-02-14 17:14:25    31.132.154.142.
2013-02-14 17:15:01    31.132.154.142.
2013-02-13 16:40:47    31.132.154.142.
```

*me need get unique ip in every day*

Comment: You might wanna consider using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` for the ordering.

Comment: Try grouping by date instead of IP. This way, you just get one row per day.

Comment: @ripa me need get unique ip in **every** day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(`date`),`ip` FROM Table GROUP BY `ip`,DATE(`date`)
```

**END**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ip) FROM Table GROUP BY date Order by date Desc
```

Comment: you query select uniq ip in one date, but me need get unique ip in **every** day. see question, i update him.